# Multiple React app with same azure app configuration ? can we Implemented SingleSIgn ON?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, msal.js, adal.js

I have 3 React Application #

1. [www.grnadfatherap.com](http://www.grnadfatherap.com)
2. [www.parenatapp.com](http://www.parenatapp.com)
3. [www.childapp.com](http://www.childapp.com)

All three have separate domain name and separate infrastructure.
and User will Login Grand app and then will go in child level app from Grand app Only.
I m using Active directory app configuration and using same tenant id app id for all 3 application.

how I can use Grand app token to all child apps and make application like SSO and not ask user to login system only once for all three application  with reacts JS I m using AUTH 2.0 code flow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support Azure AD in your react application add [@azure/msal-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-react) package to each of them, configure cacheLocation as localStorage to [enable same app between tabs SSO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#sso-between-browser-tabs-for-the-same-app) and use the [ssoSilent method to enable SSO for different apps.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-sso#sso-between-different-apps)